# ObservableCollection Behavior in MVVM Child Instance

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a strange behavior going on.  I'm using MVVM pattern, i have a binding to an Observable collection named AlarmCollection to a grid control in a View named AlarmView.  When i create multiple instances of a AlarmModelView class, and add items to AlarmCollection, all the instances display the changes.

Any changes to the ObservableColelction AlarmCollection, affects all the bound ItemSources of the grid controls.

I have tried to lock the dispatcher thread, from a similar post here, to no avail.

Is there anyway to keep the changes to this Observable collection, within each instance of the ViewModel? So that each modification does not affect any other collection in the UI thread.

Any help is appreciated.

**[edit below]**
It is strange scenario, I need to zoom/drill into what is rendered by creating the new instances of the Child MV, which in turn adds tabs to the Parent MV. The Child Views are all bound to the same Collection names, and all are **being updated by a WCF Async call**. I need X number multiple instances, based on the how deep the zoom level goes, so i need 1 ModelView object.

**How would i achieve this using CollectionChanged event or creating the ModelView's own CollectionView?**

```
    private MainViewModel _parentViewModel;
    public MainViewModel ParentViewModel
    {
        get { return _parentViewModel; }
        set
        {
            if (ParentViewModel == value) { return; }

            SetPropertyValue(ref _parentCircuitViewModel, value, "ParentViewModel");
        }
    }



    private ObservableCollection<DetailEntity> _alarmCollection;
    public ObservableCollection<DetailEntity> AlarmCollection
    {
        get
        {
            if (_alarmCollection == null)
                _alarmCollection = new ObservableCollection<DetailEntity>();

            return _alarmCollection;
        }
        private set { _alarmCollection = value; }
    }

    ServiceNode _selectedNode;

    public ServiceNode SelectedNode
    {
        get { return _selectedNode; }
        set 
        { 
                SetPropertyValue(ref _selectedNode, value, "SelectedNode");

                // render selected child node service path
                RenderSubPath(_selectedNode);

                // reset storage value
                _selectedCircuitNode = null;

        }
    }

    // Constructor
    public RenderViewModel(string servicePath  CircuitMainViewModel parentViewModel)
    {
        ServicePath = servicePath,
        ParentCircuitViewModel = parentViewModel;


        // event to handler for completed async calls 
        Client.GetAlarmsByNodeListCompleted += new EventHandler<GetAlarmsByNodeListCompletedEventArgs>(Client_GetAlarmsByNodeListCompleted);

    }

     void RenderSubPath(ServiceNode childNode)
     {
        if (childNode == null)
            return;
            // create a new child instance and add to parent VM tab
                _parentViewModel.AddServiceRenderTab(new ViewModel.Workspaces.RenderViewModel(childNode.elementPath _parentViewModel);
     }

      // wcf async webservice call to add alarm to ObservableCollection
      // ** This is updating all Collections in all Views.
      void Client_GetAlarmsByNodeListCompleted(object sender, AlarmServiceReference.GetAlarmsByNodeListCompletedEventArgs e)
      {
          try
          {
              if (e.Result == null)
                  return;

              // add to parent Netcool alarm collection
              foreach (DetailEntity alarm in nodeAlarms)
              {
                  _alarmCollection.Add(alarm);
              }

          }
     }
```

Comment: Are all of your views binding to the same `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: Looks like all your views are bound to the same collection, this result is normal! you should just create different lists, one for each view

Comment: Thanks for the response, i reposted some code.

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it sounds as though all your views are bound to the same underlying collection. For any collection you bind to, WPF will actually bind to a collection view (ICollectionView) wrapped around that collection. If you don't explicitly create your own collection view, it will use a default one. Any binding to the same collection will result in the same collection view being used.

It's hard to say without seeing your code, but it's likely you want to either use a separate instance of the underlying view model (and, hence, the collection) or you want to explicitly create separate collection views and bind to them instead.

Comment: It is strange scenerio, I am rendering and need to zoom/drill into what is rendered by creating the new instances of the Child MV, which in turn adds tabs to the Parent MV.

The Child Views are all bound to the same Collection names, and all are being updated. I need X number multiple instances, based on the how deep the zoom level goes, so i need 1 instance.  How would I create a CollectionView that will be contained in the instance? (I will update code in my original answer)